# C++ Windows process ID in binary

Tags: c++, windows, binary, pid

I would like to write in C++ on Windows the prcoess ID of the program (by the program itself) in a file (binary is preferred). 
I saw the use of the function: GetProcessId, but i didn't manage to work with it.
1) How to use it?
 2) how to tranfer the value into binary and write to the file?

Thanks

Comment: you don't know _how to write a DWORD into a file_, right?

Comment: yes and I didn't know to change it binary representation

Comment: These are two unrelated questions - both extremely elementary ones, to be honest. How to get process ID, and how to write a number to a binary file.

Comment: the numbers _are_ in binary representation, no need to change them. for writing into a file, look up any example on `ofstream`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`GetCurrentProcessId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the process id of the current process. Then you can use [`ultoa`](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~kev/pp/RESOURCES/cplusplus/ref/cstdlib/ultoa.html) to convert that number to a string using base `2` (and a buffer of size `sizeof(DWORD) * 8 + 1`), then you can use [`ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/) or [`fwrite`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/) to write it to a file.

Example:

```
DWORD id = GetCurrentProcessId();

char buf[sizeof(DWORD) * 8 + 1];
ultoa(id, buf, 2);

ofstream f("file.txt");
f << id;
```

I assume that by "transfer the value to binary" you mean turn it into a representation so that when you open the file, it looks like `1001011110101` or something. If you just want to see it as a number, then don't use `itoa` but do the rest.

Comment: But the function waits for parameter that I don't know what to send it

Comment: @Roman which function? You write the return value of `ultoa` to the file.

Comment: What's a little confusing is that the question asks for a binary file.

Comment: @David uhh... yeah, I just noticed that. And on top of that, he said "binary is _preferred_." The question needs clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Get the process ID by calling `GetCurrentProcessId()`. You don't need to convert that into a binary representation since integral types are already stored in binary. Just write it to the file.